# Why is this output?

Tags: c, function

Here is the Code of:

```
# include <stdio.h> 
# define scanf  "%s Geeks For Geeks " 
main() 
{ 
    printf(scanf, scanf); 
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Output is:`%s Geeks For Geeks Geeks For Geeks`

How is this output generated?

Comment: Repeating  "Geeks" in the string adds confusion.  Try `# define scanf  "%s Abc def ghi "` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your printf will become

```
printf(scanf, scanf);

         |
         |
        \ /

printf("%s Geeks For Geeks ", "%s Geeks For Geeks" ); 

         |
         |       //%s is replaced with "%s Geeks For Geeks" string
        \ /

printf("%s Geeks For Geeks Geeks For Geeks ");
```

and on the console

```
%s Geeks For Geeks Geeks For Geeks
```

> Aside: Please don't do this kind of coding. It sucks.

Comment: Try not to answer such questions. Simply put, you are not helping them.